# @Query named parameters for MongoDb Spring repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

Is it possible to use named parameters for a @Query method in a mongodb repository, just like we can do with a jpa repository (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html section 2.3.5)?

As an example, I would like to use the following code:

```
@Query("{'store' : :store, 'app' : :app }")
List<T> findByStoreAndApp(@Param("store") String store, @Param("app") String app);
```

instead of:

```
@Query("{'store' : ?0, 'app' : ?1 }")
List<T> findByStoreAndApp(String store, String app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the spring boot does provide this function in its source code.

You can create an interface and extends **MongoRepository**
It provides some simple method, and you don't need the implement it.
Just like use the JpaRepository.

```html
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> var1);

    List<T> findAll();

    List<T> findAll(Sort var1);

    <S extends T> S insert(S var1);

    <S extends T> List<S> insert(Iterable<S> var1);
}
```

However, if you need to do some special query. You could just @Autowired the **MongoTemplate** and use its own method. And for redis, springboot even doesn't provide the Repository like MongoRepository. You could just only use the template like StringRedisTemplate for query operation.
May be latter, spring boot would add the same function like JpaRepository for NoSql. But now, it doesn't provide this function.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible, try:

```
@Query("{'store' : :#{#store}, 'app' : :#{#app} }")
List<T> findByStoreAndApp(@Param("store") String store, @Param("app") String app);
```

The support of SpEL expressions in @Query was introduced in Spring Data MongoDB 1.8.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.projection.expressions